# Joomla 3.9 Installation stalled

Tags: installation

I'm replacing an old laptop and trying to get a Joomla 3.9.21 test site runing on the new computer. Since I've done this in the past, decided to do so manually instead of using XAMPP.

Running on Windows 10, all Apache, php, mysql and phpmyadmin are working correctly. I can access localhost files and been able to handle the database.

When I run localhost/mysite/installation I can go through all the steps up to the point to click the INSTALL button.

The installer actually writes on the database 14 tables and suddenly it stalls. The installation progress bar stops. If I access the site in a new tab at this time, the installation page comes up again. Is there a way to show the installation steps taking place to find out where is the problem to find it's solution ?

I presume it could / should be a config error either in Apache, PHP or MySql.

I've already done the following:

Apache httpd.conf

```
ServerName localhost
PHPIniDir "c:\php"
LoadModule php7_module "c:\php\php7apache2_4.dll"
AddHandler application x-httpd-php .php
```

php.ini

```
uncommented extensions for curl, mbstring and mysqli
```

Thanks

Comment: Nevermind... increased max_execution_time in php.ini and that got me going.

Comment: Welcome to JSE and thanks for joining us.  Please take our [tour] to better understand how things work here.  I must ask you to formally resolve your question.  Please express your resolving technique in an educational manner as a new answer to your question then delete your comment.  It is possible that a volunteer may advise a different or better solution than the one you have implemented. After a little time, the system will allow you to "accept" your own answer. Accepting an answer informs the system that a page is resolved. All questions should progress to a system-recognized resolution.

Comment: @GeoLeo68 please answer your own question and set it as solved - good for you and others that have a similar problem

Answer (score 1):

Head to **xampp\htdocs\Your joomla files\installation\sql\mysql** and in this folder, find the **Joomla.sql** file in the folder, use your editor to open it and do the following:

1. search for

> "ENGINE=InnoDB"

2. Replace all occurrences with

> "ENGINE=MyIsam"

3. Try the installation again.

If the above would not solve the problem, navigate to **xampp\php \ php.ini** , open the file with your text editor, search and update the following value **max_execution_time = 30** to **max_execution_time = 280** or any value higher. Restart your Apache and try installation again.

See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21510660/joomla-3-installation-freezes-at-creating-database-table)

I hope it helps.